# Assign the value of a variable based on another variable which is related to column names of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, get

I have a data frame with the following variables:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = seq(1:5),
                 Price.A = c(10,12,14,16,18), 
                 Price.B = c(6,7,9,8,5), 
                 Price.C = c(27,26,25,24,23), 
                 Choice = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"))
```

I want to create a variable called *Expenditure*, which picks the value from *Price.A*, *Price.B* or *Price.C* depending on the value of the variable *Choice*.

I tried to create it with the following code:

```
df$Expenditure <- with(df, get(paste("Price.", Choice, sep ="")))
```

However, that returns the value of *Price.A* for all observations.

In my real application, instead of A, B and C, I have hundreds of names, so an *ifelse* command is not feasible.

Does anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: `df$Expenditure <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(df$ID), function(x) df[x, paste("Price.", df$Choice[x], sep = "")]))`

Comment: If ID column is unique and serial type, then `df$Expenditure <- unlist(lapply(df$ID), function(x) df[x, paste("Price.", df$Choice[x], sep = "")]))`

Comment: @Sathish That gives errors. You've got an unmatched parenthesis but even if you fix that it still won't run.

Comment: @Hack-R I corrected the parenthesis. It works `df$Expenditure <- unlist(lapply(df$ID, function(x) df[x, paste("Price.", df$Choice[x], sep = "")])`

Comment: I'd like to thank all for the replies.  Most answers work fine,  and I just used the one that was easiest for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of *apply based approaches:

```
df$Expenditure <- sapply(seq_along(df[[1]]), function(i) { 
    df[i, sprintf("Price.%s", df$Choice[i])] 
})

df$Expenditure <- mapply(function(x, y) {
        df[x, sprintf("Price.%s", y)]
    }, row.names(df), df$Choice
)
```

The second one assumes your object has the default `row.names` of `1:nrow(df)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
df$Expenditure[df$Choice=="A"] <- df$Price.A[df$Choice=="A"]
df$Expenditure[df$Choice=="B"] <- df$Price.B[df$Choice=="B"]
df$Expenditure[df$Choice=="C"] <- df$Price.C[df$Choice=="C"]
```

Here's how to scale it up with a loop:

```
df$Expenditure <- NA

for(i in unique(df$Choice)){
  j <- paste0("Price.",i)
  df$Expenditure[df$Choice==i] <- df[df$Choice==i,colnames(df) == j]
}
```

> ```
>   ID Price.A Price.B Price.C Choice Expenditure
> 1  1      10       6      27      A          10
> 2  2      12       7      26      A          12
> 3  3      14       9      25      B           9
> 4  4      16       8      24      B           8
> 5  5      18       5      23      C          23
> ```

You could easily wrap this into a function and use `apply` if you prefer.

There are also lots of more overly complicated ways to do this, though I think it's a terrible practice to use some 3rd party package to do this when base R does a wonderful job. Here's one:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = seq(1:5),
                 PriceA = c(10,12,14,16,18), 
                 PriceB = c(6,7,9,8,5), 
                 PriceC = c(27,26,25,24,23), 
                 Choice = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"))
require(sqldf)
df$Expenditure <- unname(sqldf("SELECT   
                                 CASE   
                                  WHEN Choice == 'A' THEN PriceA   
                                  WHEN Choice == 'B' THEN PriceB
                                  WHEN Choice == 'C' THEN PriceC
                                END
                                from df"))
```

Answer (score 2):

It would probably make more sense to reshape your data. Currently your data is not in a "tidy" format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% gather(Price, Expendeture, -ID, -Choice) %>%
    filter(Price == paste0("Price.", Choice)) %>%
    select(-Price)
```

Otherwise you could do matrix-indexing of a matrix

```
cols <- grep("Price", names(df), value=T)
mm <- as.matrix(df[, cols])
colidx <- match(paste0("Price.", df$Choice), cols)
df$Expenditure <- mm[cbind(1:length(colidx), colidx)]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
   df$Expenditure[i] <- with(df[i, ], get(paste("Price.", Choice, sep="")))
}
```